# Efficient way to search List of String Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, search

I have Structure like this,

```
String[] variable1= new String["ABC", "FSS" , "FSFS", "GDGDDS"];
String[] variable2= new String["SA", "GS" , "QE", "HF"];


static List<String[]> allList = new List<String[]>();;

allList .Add(variable1);
allList .Add(variable2);
```

When a `String` is provided i want to search `allList`  and provide the result which array if were it found .

Any help archiving this in a Efficient way?

Comment: What if string exists in several arrays?

Comment: it will not , it will be unique .. as my requirement !

Comment: I would consider restructuring this using a Dictionary/Hashtable approach. I would categorize the potential keys and store each array in a Dictionary entry. The proposed structure doesn't lend itself to efficient access as you have to do a linear search through all lists/arrays

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Did you mean `String[] variable1 = new String[] { /* ... */ };`? If not, this could be an important difference.

Comment: @TGH I like your approach. any code examples ?

Comment: Here's some stuff to get you started http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: Do you need to know if your search exists at all or do you need the list and index of that list it is contained in? If the former I would just load all the words in to a `HashSet<string>`,  if the latter a `Dictionary<String,Tuple<int,int>>` and have the value hold the index the string is in.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain only the list is enough , text will be unique between all lists .. i have no use of the index for my requirement.

Comment: Actually i'm building a lexicon what these internal string arrays are for mention what word type its belongs to..

Comment: do you really need to maintain the original lists at all? If the reason is just to identify the source I think I would flatten the strings into a dictionary as keys (you said they were unique) and add a listID as the value. That way you only need to look up the key in the list to know which of the individual lists it originated from. er... what @ScottChamberlain said - I guess :P

Answer (score 6):

Both provided solutions run in linear time, which will be way too slow if you have lots of words and make lots of queries.

You can use a Dictionary. A Dictionary uses a hash table internally and it will be much, much faster.

To put all the strings in a dictionary, you can do:

```
Dictionary<String, String[]> dict = new Dictionary<String, String[]>();
foreach(String[] arr in allList)
    foreach(String str in arr)
        dict[str] = arr;
```

And then you can easily search it:

```
String s = "ABC";
if(dict.ContainsKey(s))
    // result is dict[s]
else
    // String is not in any array
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also remember, the loook-ups will be case sensitive by default, but you can pass in a [StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) to the dictionary's constructor and it will match both `abc` and `ABC`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
var output=allList.Where(x=>(string.Join(",", x)+",").IndexOf(input+",")!=-1)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```